# Convert latin to cyrillic in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, localisation, convert

Is there any plugin (free or commercial) which can translate latin into cyrillic? So plugin would work like this I would uplod data for news, products etc. in Magento Admin panel in Latin letters - but in frontend letters would be converted into Cyrillics?

Thanks for help

Comment: please specify magento  version?

Comment: @AmitBera it is 1.9.3.7